# Need to get the weblogic hostname where my application is deployed from within my java code

Tags: java, weblogic

I have the following piece of code from where i can get the Admin server name and the port.

```
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        String serverName = System.getProperty("weblogic.Name");

        MBeanServer server = (MBeanServer)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");

        ObjectName objName = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=" + serverName + ",Type=Server");
        Integer port = (Integer)server.getAttribute(objName, "ListenPort");

        System.out.println("Server Name :" + serverName + " PORT :" + port);
```

But I also need the weblogic hostname along with the server name. Not sure how to get that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in addition, you want the "listen address":

Via Java/JMX:

```
String listenAddress=(String)server.getAttribute(objName,"ListenAddress");
```

Via WLST script:

```
cd('Servers/' + serverName) 
listenAddress=str(get('ListenAddress')) 
print "Listen Address is: " , listenAddress
```